# Except with LIKE condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings which holds file paths.

```
List<string> allFilesWithPathList = new List<string>();

allFilesWithPathList.Add(@"G:\Test\A.sql");
allFilesWithPathList.Add(@"G:\Test\B.sql");
allFilesWithPathList.Add(@"G:\Test\C.sql");

return allFilesWithPathList;
```

I have another list which holds a subset of files – but it has only the file name; not the path.

```
List<string> excludeList = new List<string>();
excludeList.Add("B.sql");
```

Now I need to get files from allFilesWithPathList that is not present in excludeList. Currently I am doing the following, using `EXCEPT`, after creating another list with file names only.

```
List<string> allFileNamesOnlyList = new List<string>();
foreach (string fileNameWithPath in allFilesWithPathList)
{
    //Remove path and get only file name
    int pos = fileNameWithPath.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1;
    string value = fileNameWithPath.Substring(pos, fileNameWithPath.Length - pos);
    allFileNamesOnlyList.Add(value);
}

//EXCEPT logic
List<string> eligibleListToProcess = allFileNamesOnlyList.Except(excludeList).ToList();
```

What is the best way in `LINQ` to get this logic working without introducing another list like the above?

Note: I am using `.Net 4.5`

**Complete code**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> allFilesWithPathList = GetAllFilesWithPath();

        List<string> excludeList = new List<string>();
        excludeList.Add("B.sql");

        List<string> allFileNamesOnlyList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string fileNameWithPath in allFilesWithPathList)
        {
            //Remove path and get only file name
            int pos = fileNameWithPath.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1;
            string value = fileNameWithPath.Substring(pos, fileNameWithPath.Length - pos);
            allFileNamesOnlyList.Add(value);
        }

        //EXCEPT logic
        List<string> eligibleListToProcess = allFileNamesOnlyList.Except(excludeList).ToList();

        //Print all eligible files
        foreach (string s in eligibleListToProcess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<string> GetAllFilesWithPath()
    {
        List<string> allFilesWithPathList = new List<string>();

        allFilesWithPathList.Add(@"G:\Test\A.sql");
        allFilesWithPathList.Add(@"G:\Test\B.sql");
        allFilesWithPathList.Add(@"G:\Test\C.sql");

        return allFilesWithPathList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
allFilesWithPathList.Where(x => !excludeList.Any(y => x.EndsWith(y)))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
allFilesWithPathList.Where(path => !allFileNamesOnlyList.Contains(Path.GetFileName(path));
```

There are two improvements here.

1. `Path.GetFileName` is much better than splitting the path yourself.
2. `IEnumerable.Where` in conjunction with `ICollection.Contains` to actually query the list in a succinct and easy to read way.